# Windows Batch Script to Execute all Scripts in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have written the below command to execute all the scripts in a directory in ascending order.

```
cd Scripts
for /R %%i in (*) do sqlcmd -S%db% -E -b -i"%%i"
```

Here it works fine it the count is 9. When the count is 10,11..... post execution of number 1. script its executes 10, 11 and then it runs 2

If anyone can help me, where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: there is no mistake. That's the way, files are sorted. What are the exact names of the scripts?

Comment: You can temporarily change the count so it conforms by adding a number to the code, but will need to see an example of the file names in order to make it work.

Comment: or even better, if you have influence of the naming: name them with leading zeros.

Comment: 1st Test case:  1.Script.sql  followed 2.Script.sql . -- Passed



1.Script.sql  followed 12.Script.sql & followed by  2.Script.sql --- Failed

Comment: @Stephan Let me try that, adding 0 to the file names

Comment: `for /L %%i in (1,1,12) do sqlcmd -S%db% -E -b -i"%%i.script.sql"`?

Comment: @stephan or to get the number of files first. `for /f %%i in ('dir *.sql ^| find /i "File(s)"') do set "max=%%i"` and then your script... `for /L %%i in (1,1,%max%) do sqlcmd -S%db% -E -b -i"%%i.script.sql"`

Comment: @Gerhard: that's language dependent. Better: `for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.sql^|find /c /v ""') do set max=%%i`